# Rails: Including nested associative attributes in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have three models as follows :

```
 #Product Model
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_one :address
        validates :title, :description, :user_id, presence: true
        validates :product_type, numericality:{:greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 2}, presence: true
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
    end




    #Address Model
    class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :city
        belongs_to :product

        def related_city
            city = address.city
        end
    end

#City Model
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses
end
```

I am fetching a Product but I need to include associative attributes as well in my JSON response except few attributes.
Here is what I have done so far :

```
def show
        product = Product.find(params[:id])
        render json: product.to_json(:include => { :address => {
                             :include => { :city => {
                                             :only => :name } },
                             },:user =>{:only=>{:first_name}}}), status: 200
    end
```

This is giving me a syntax error. If I remove the user it is working fine but I need user's name as well in response. Moreover how would I write the above code using ruby's new hash syntax?

Comment: Using the new syntax usually results in less stuff to get wrong. `:include => { ... }` becomes `include: { ... }` which tends to be easier to read. The only reason for using the old style is if you still have reason to use the scary-old 1.8 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve that problem using this gem: [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). It will let you create serializers for each model and use them to render the formatted JSON as you want. Take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the fifth line of your show method you have a comma surrounded by curly braces. Here is the hash sans comma, in the new syntax:

```
def show
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  render json: product.to_json(include: { address: {
                     include: { city: {
                                     only: :name }}}},
                     user: {only:{:first_name}}), status:200
end
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but I'm getting this error : "/home/paras/rails/lost_and_found/app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => user: {only:{:first_name}}}), status:200 ^"

Comment: Oh, you probably need to move on bracket from line 6 to 5. I edited my hash.

Comment: No luck. Still getting the following error : /home/paras/rails/lost_and_found/app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => user: {only:{:first_name}}), status:200 ^
#31  user: {only:{:first_name}}), status:200